# Proper way to make function calls in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

What is best practice for making a function call on a wordpress page?

For instance if you want to call `my_special_function();` on the home page, where is the proper place to put the function call (ie `home-page.php`, `/template-parts/content-page.php` etc.).

```
<?php if( function_exists( my_special_function ) ) {
    my_special_function();
} ?>
```

FYI Im using Underscores theme.

I've seen a few comments regarding shortcode. Would something like the below WP page template with the shortcode inserted be a best practice over just calling the function on that page?

So if I wanted the function to be called in the page template below I would just insert the shortcode wherever I want it on that page template or just is just calling the function is sufficient or best practice

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Home Page
 *
 * The template for displaying the home page.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Rollins_Ridge
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

                // insert Shortcode
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[special_function_shortcode]') ;?>

               // or just call the function
               my_special_function();

               // or something else im not aware of
               code here;

            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;

            endwhile; // End of the loop ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: Depends on the theme implementation. Some themes comes only with `index.php`, other comes with `home-page.php`. What are the php files in your theme root directory ? In addition. modern themes comes with Page Builders which is more difficult to say where it can go a function.

Comment: Another think, if you are not familiar with what is the right place to run a function is to create your own shortcode, and then you can place the  shortcode in your content instead of the theme.

Comment: @MerianosNikos thanks for the response. Im using the Underscores starter theme and so far I've just been putting the function calls in the "content-area" div of whichever page I wanted to make the call on. I was just wondering if that was the best way to accomplish this or if there is a more proper way. I am not very familiar with shortcode yet I'll take a look at the docs.

Comment: you are totally fine.The WordPress it is really very simple, thus you should go the strait way and stop thinking for more complex solutions ;)

Comment: @MerianosNikos lol ok I guess I will just keep doing what I'm doing just wanted to make sure there wasnt going to be any issues in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't edit themes core files.
the proper way is using functions.php file in child theme directory.

you can add your function in this file and create shortocde using wordpress hook
like

```
my_special_function(){

//Your content goes here.

echo "This is proper way";

}
add_shortcode('special_function_shortcode','my_special_function');
```

and use following shortocde anywhere on site.

```
in wordpress page use [special_function_shortcode]
and in php use
<?php echo do_shortcode('[special_function_shortcode]') ;?>
```

Comment: You can just call the function directly in php, no need to use the do_shortcode function.

Comment: @kunruh I usually just call the function directly in the page template but I was looking for a best practice way of how it should be done.

Comment: @MoxDev If you are going to use the function in a php template that you made yourself, best practice would be to call the function directly.